# query and formatting string at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have a simple query,

```
select * from P_Bld
where datep = (select max(datep) from P_Bld)
and codeBlood like 'nm_%'
order by codeBlood
```

This works fine and returns the data as shown below

```
codeBlood     num
nm_aab        1
nm_abc        2
nm_rst        3
```

I was wondering if it is possible to change the codeBlood column so it does not include the 'nm_' and also make the rest of the string uppercase so I would get something like below,

```
codeBlood     num
AAB        1
ABC        2
RST        3
```

Is this possible?

Comment: apologies it should have been rf_ there is another table with nm_. I have put it all to nm_ in this post. Thanks for spotting that

Comment: If you have a column `codeBlood`, does that mean you have a translation table for something "human readable"?  Shouldn't you be using that instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do,
First replace "nm_" by blank using `Replace()` function & then convert remaining string to Uppercase bu `Upper()` function

```
select Upper(Replace(codeBlood,'nm_','')) as codeBlood,num from P_Bld
where datep = (select max(datep) from P_Bld)
and codeBlood like 'nm_%'
order by codeBlood
```

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is same, try this

```
select Upper(substring(codeBlood,4,length(CodeBllod))),num from P_Bld
where datep = (select max(datep) from P_Bld)
and codeBlood like 'rf_%'
order by codeBlood
```

Comment: 3 functions used vs 2 functions used. Will it affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it like the following

```
select SUBSTRING ( UPPER(codeBlood) ,4 , LEN(codeBlood) ),num from P_Bld
where datep = (select max(datep) from P_Bld)
and codeBlood like 'rf_%'
order by codeBlood
```